# Excel VBA Based on values in one column choose whether to transfer to next empty line or to leave an empty row first

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook where it has a 'Master Sheet' worksheet that has all the products for a project on it. Based on the Delivery Stage column("BF") they are then transferred to the correct Stage Sheets.[Layout of the Worksheets. Stage worksheets go up to 24. 6-24 are hidden.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRpyL.png)

The products are sorted into Types or groups of the same product not by the stage. There are empty rows between the different groups. Currently the code I have transfers the products to the correct stages but with no division between the different groups of products.[View of Master Sheet sorted by Product, not by Stage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ24M.png) For example; There should be an empty row between D10 and D05 as this is the next product for Stage 1 but is not the same as D10.

My current code is this:

```
Sub LineCopy()

RowClear.ClearRows

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, x As Long, xLR As Long, y As Long
LR = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 10 To LR
    For x = 1 To 24
        If Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("BF" & i).Value = x Then
            Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Stage " & x & " Sheet").Range("A" &     Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
    Next x
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution here would be to add a column which gives the product / grouping, then you can just check whether the value on the Master sheet matches the latest  value in the stage sheet.

The other alternative is to keep track of whether you need to skip a row. Assuming that it's possible to have multiple entries for a stage within a group, you'd need to track this separately for each Stage sheet, using an array.

```
Sub LineCopy()
    RowClear.ClearRows

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, x As Long, xLR As Long, y As Long
    LR = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create an array to track whether each sheet needs to skip a line
    'Default is False
    Dim SkipLine(24) As Boolean


    For i = 10 To LR
        'Rather than looping twice, we will get the value of x from column BF
        x = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("BF" & i)

        'If the cell is empty, x will be zero
        If x = 0 Then
            'We fill the array with the value of True every sheet
            'They all need to skip a row now
            For j = 1 To 24
                SkipLine(j) = True
            Next
        Else
            'If cell BF is not empty, we copy the row
            Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
            'Find the empty cell at the bottom of the stage sheet
            Set PasteRow = Sheets("Stage " & x & " Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            'Check whether we need to skip a row for this Stage Sheet
            If SkipLine(x) = True Then
                'If we need to skip a row, offset the PasteRow variable by another row
                Set PasteRow = PasteRow.Offset(1)
                'Update the array to show that we no longer need to skip a line on this sheet
                SkipLine(x) = False
            End If
            'Paste the data
            PasteRow.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```